# How to get the type of a List Column in SharePoint REST API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sharepoint

My goal is to figure out the type of column in my SharePoint list in order to populate a form with with correct type of field. After doing some digging, I found [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints#NavigationProperties) in the documentation about accessing specific properties.

I also found [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/225418/get-columns-type-via-rest) asking the same thing I am, but was never resolved. In my code, I tried

```
..url.../_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('...list name...')/columnName
```

However I get 404 errors when it can't find the resource.

What is the correct syntax for accessing a column in a SharePoint list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use the URL below to get the type of field.

```
http://siteurl/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/fields?$select=Title,TypeAsString,TypeDisplayName&$filter=InternalName eq 'Title'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery from http://labs.steveottenad.com/getting-ows_metainfo-with-spservices/

If you use the SPServices library (link) to grab info from lists, you’ve more than likely ran into an instance where the information you need is contained in a gnarly string inside the “ows_MetaInfo” attribute. There is a very easy solution to change this large string into its appropriate attributes, making the information contained in it super easy to access. Just include CAMLViewFields: “” in your initial SPServices call, and you’ll now have access to all that information as attributes instead of a string

Comment: Even the creator of SPServices is moving to REST calls: https://sympmarc.com/series/moving-from-spservices-to-rest/.